# Ignoring \vskipnextgrid at the top of a page before \section

Tags: sectioning, grid-typesetting

Consider a document using the `gridset` package, and some plain text at the top of two pages. But one of the pages is preceded by a `\vskipnextgrid` like so:

```
\RequirePackage{gridset}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\newpage
Foo

\newpage
\vskipnextgrid
Foo
\end{document}
```

As I'd expect, "Foo" appears at the same height on both pages.

*However*, if I wrap "Foo" in a header, then the header on the second page is lower down the page than the header on the first page,

```
\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{Foo}  % <-- header

\newpage
\vskipnextgrid
\section{Foo}  % <-- header
\end{document}
```

How do I stop this behaviour, so that both headers are level (like with the plain text)?

Comment: You will experience the same with a blank line or par before the text.

Comment: @AndrewSwann if I replace `\vskipnextgrid` with `\par`, then both of my headings are at the same height.

Comment: I meant replacing `\section` by a blank line or `\par` and keeping the `\vskipnextgrid`.  I would conclude that you should not use `\vskipnextgrid` after a page break in all cases, rather just before `\section`.

Comment: @AndrewSwannthe problem is that we're programmatically generating LaTeX, and can't control when a `\vskipnextgrid` gets shunted to the top of a random page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not thoroughly tested, because `gridset` says (in 2008) it is an alpha version so I conclude it never got finalized.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gridset}

\def\myvskipnextgrid{\ifdim\pagetotal=0pt
  % SKIPPING (TEST MODE)
  \else\expandafter\vskipnextgrid\fi}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo1}

\newpage
\myvskipnextgrid

\section{Foo2}

blabla

\myvskipnextgrid

\section{Foo3}

blabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. This definitely works for the provided test case, although worth noting that I poked around a bit more, and if the `\section` is pushed onto a new page (eg by having a page full of content before it, rather than using `\newpage`), then this doesn't work.